# Trying to use proxies with Requests-HTML

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I read the documentation, it seems like there really is no difference than request.get

here's my code:

```
testurl = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/'
proxy = {'http': 'http://144.168.191.153:port'}

def getresponse(url):
   s = HTMLSession()
   r = s.get(url, proxies = proxy)

   IP = {
        'myip':  (.....  xpath, first=True).text
      }
   print(IP)


getresponse(testurl)
```

I tried this and it's still showing my own ip instead of the proxy that I should be connected to.

I've tested with a simple request, the site above works with the ip showing as it tends to be.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type port:

proxy = {'http': 'http://144.168.191.153:*****port*****'}

or try use some proxy from this site -> https://free-proxy-list.net/, for me works fine.